# how to hide the overflow coming from my corner ribbon div?

Tags: html, css, overflow

On line 11 of my Codepen (link) I have the following

```
body{overflow:hidden;}
```

that was my last attempt to hide the overflow of content to the right side of the body...

A div called ".talk" is positioned absolute to the corner as a ribbon & "call to action"

```
 .talk{height:50px; width:370px; position:absolute; right:0; top:0; transform:rotate(40deg); margin-right:-100px;}
```

However

```
body{overflow:hidden;}
```

Hides a lot of content below the first pink icon ... how can I hide the ribbons overflow without affecting the layout of the page?

http://codepen.io/gebrutommy/pen/tLHFh?editors=0100

Comment: Was able to solve with with a more specific css property "overflow-x" and applied "hidden" value

Comment: I may have a better solution for you. You better have a wrapper for your absolute position div which is your call to action.

Comment: Hope this answer will help you to enhance your hack [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16671476/6426617)

Answer (score 3):

Do this change

in your CSS remove `body{overflow:hidden;}`

add `.text{position: relative; overflow: hidden; }`

then move `talk div` to be child of `text` like

```
 <div class="text">
    <div class="mix-text">
      <h1>Gitter</h1>
      <h2>Where developers come to talk</h2>
    </div>
      <div class="talk"><a href="https://gitter.im/tommygebru">LET'S CHAT</a></div>
  </div>
```

then add to

```
.talk { overflow: hidden;}
```

Done.

Here is live example : http://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/YGwpZK

Comment: That solution makes so much sense... I cant believe i overlooked that, but I guess because i was hacking away I didnt consider... thanks @Majid good solution!!

Comment: If it works for you then accept it hope it can help others in the future.

Comment: haha hope i didnt go overboard with the upvotes, I can upvote now!! :)

Comment: Excellent. The parent just needs to tell the child not to overflow :)